# Why are my HTML input selection change event handlers not firing?

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I've got some selections like so:

```
<select>
  <option id="Alabama">Alabama</option>
  <option id="Alaska">Alaska</option>
  <option id="Arizona">Arizona</option>
  <option id="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
  <option id="California">California</option>
    . . .
</select>
<div id="map"></div>
```

...and gomap (jQuery plugin for google maps) code to fire when a selection is made:

```
$('#Alabama').change(function() {
      $("#map").removeData();
      $("#map").goMap({ 
            latitude: 32.806673, 
            longitude: -86.791133, 
            zoom: 7 
      }); 
});
```

...yet selecting the items does nothing - the change handlers don't fire. Why not?

Comment: You should bind the handler to the `select` and not to the `options`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the problem is that you are calling the id of the option.

try giving the select an id. options also should be values and not id.

http://jsfiddle.net/MV2dn/

```
$('#selectDD').on("change",function() {
      $("#map").removeData();
      /*$("#map").goMap({ 
            latitude: 32.806673, 
            longitude: -86.791133, 
            zoom: 7 
      }); */
    alert($(this).val());
});
```